# WCF IConnectionRegister Duplicate Log Entries

Tags: .net, wcf

I have some WCF log entries that have an action of http://tempuri.org/IConnectionRegister/Duplicate with a corresponding http://tempuri.org/IConnectionRegister/DuplicateResponse. Could someone shed any light as to what these are please? They seem to contain socket information, but I am curious as to the name "duplicate".

Thanks

Comment: Can it have something to do with NetTcP? I am logging a service. If I choose http binding these entries don't appear. However, if I choose NetTCP binding these log entries appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection duplicator is the technique used by port sharing. When a connection comes over the default port sharing. The owning process needs to hand of the connection to the process or server that actually will service the request.

eg. you can have 2 services under the same port in different processes.

process1 ==> net.tcp://...:808/Service1
process2 ==> net.tcp://...:808/Service2

The port sharing process will hand of the incoming connection to the appropriate process and duplicate the socket for you.